# Automated Builds on Branches for TFS

Tags: tfs, build-automation, branch

In TFS, you are able to create automated builds and create branches (well, hopefully. ;) )
I have the following structure:

```
->Trunk
->Branches
   -> Branch A
```

If you create an automated build, you are able to create a trigger for the build.  In my case I want to create a build for Branch A so that when a checkin occurs Branch A is built.  However, if I do a checkin in the Trunk, my automated build will start as it detected a checkin.  Is there anyway that I can do builds per branch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your workspace for the branch in the build definition is set to the branch only and not to the root of your project.  My guess is that TFS does file change detection by workspace.  You'd want it set to $Project/Branches/Branch A in your example.

Comment: In TFS 2008 you set the workspace template in the build definition page (Builds Node, Edit Build Definition, Workspace)

Comment: "My guess is that TFS does file change detection by workspace." This is unfortunately the case.